# What build, compile and support libraries are recommended for production?

Tags: android

I just had one doubt and would like some clarification about it. So I am building an android app that will go into production within 2-3 weeks. Its an e-commerce app on which I will be selling goods.

I plan to target API 16+ and have done sufficient research to know that most of my target market will have 16+ on their android phones.

The issue I am facing is which build, compile and app support libraries should I use in terms of the version? I know as of now 23.0 has been released and appcombat library goes upto 23.0.1 but a developer I know had suggested that I stick to using 22 and 21.1.2 as they are most stable as of now. Is this true? For example in node.js, versions are classified as per their stability and a disclaimer is given for the most recent ones that are still in their testing phase.

I dont feel this is an opinion based question as stability is more based on fact and experience rather than a personal opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your friend has a good perspective. Historically, if you review the Android release history:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history

you will notice that, compared to API releases:

https://source.android.com/source/build-numbers.html

there is definite evidence of "instability" - in other words, considering a previous target release version is probably a good idea, unless you (or your team) are intimately familiar with both the requirements of your app and the release version changes.

Otherwise, it is generally practical to target a release version that is not the most recent. However, it is also important to consider that more recent releases usually include features, libraries and components that could make your development effort substantially lower.

In other words, while you are likely correct that this in not an "opinion" based question or response, the decision is highly dependent on business requirements, feature requirements, and the ability or expectation to adapt to changes (either because your app needs to migrate to a more recent build or else because targeting the most recent available build results in problems that require either regressing to a previous build target or migrating to the next release).

Also, please note that the most recent release may not support (or adequately support) older versions. So if you have a requirement to support older versions, then just setting the minVersion may not be sufficient. You may actually need to target an older API in order to support older features. However, generally support for older features are incorporated into AppCompat libraries...

So, even though it is not an "opinion based" question, it really is very highly dependent upon a long list of business requirements, resource constraints and projects expectations such that it may appear to be an opinion. There are very few people with enough insight into a particular project to make these decisions appropriately. Or else, it is random and you can just do what you like!!

Comment: My first priority is to support API 16 as my market research indicates majority of my customer base is around 4.0+. I have been trying out android 23 and its been giving me issues with my existing code. I guess I will stick with 22 until majority of my user base upgrades to android 5.0 +.

Comment: If it helps, I have apps targeting API 16 as well as API 19 right now. Migration is too expensive to accomplish, despite recommendations. But I have some apps at API 22.

Comment: Migration is hard and needs a lot of work but If the most important thing for me is supporting devices above 4.0 then I guess I dont have too much of a choice since 23 has known to give issues and isnt compiling well with my current code.